# How to insert slash "/" before slash "#" in route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using the microfrontend concept and I have two projects, which are:

- Primary
- Secondary

The **primary** uses `BrowserRouter` and the **secondary** `HashRouter` to **not lose** `remoteEntry` and etc.

But the route in the main when accessing and loading the microfrontend is looking like this:

```
http://localhost:3003/national#/pre-ticket/ABCDEF
```

But I would like it to look like this:

```
http://localhost:3003/national/#/pre-ticket/ABCDEF
```

How can I do this?

**PRIMARY PROJECT**

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <GlobalComponents />

    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={() => <div />} />
        <Route exact path='/404' component={() => <Error404 />} />

        {MICROFRONTEND_LIST.map(({ service, module, registry, data }) => (
            <Route
                exact
                key={data.basename}
                path={data.basename}
                component={() => (
                    <MicrofrontendArsenalComponent service={service} module={module} registry={registry} basename={data.basename} />
                )}
            />
        ))}

        <Route path='*' component={() => <Redirect exact to='/404' />} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**SECONDARY PROJECT**

```
<HashRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route
                    exact
                    path='/'
                    component={HomePage}
                />

                <Route
                    exact
                    path='/pre-ticket'
                    component={CreateOrEditPreTicket}
                />

                <Route
                    path='/pre-ticket/:id'
                    component={CreateOrEditPreTicket}
                />

                <Route
                    path='/suggestedOperation/:id'
                    component={CreateSuggestedOperationPage}
                />

                <Route
                    path='*'
                    component={MemoizedRedirectComponent}
                />
            </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
```

Comment: You might be able to set the `basename` prop on the `HashRouter`. Would it be possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox demo of this routing code that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Sorry I can't, as it's the microfrontend concept, I wouldn't be able to connect these two projects there.

But, in relation to the basename I already tried and it doesn't help.

Comment: Is `MicrofrontendArsenalComponent` rendering the `Hashrouter`? Or is something else? I could probably stand something up myself, but was hoping you could provide most of the routing structure yourself that we could start from that instead of starting from scratch.

Comment: It inserts Microfrontend into the main project, that is, the secondary project with its routes. Probably the control I want must be done in the parent project that has the BrowserRouter.